# How to deploy ASP.NET grid view solution in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, asp.net

I have created a ASP.NET grid view and and have blind the data with sqldatasource. Also I have code behind for update row in the grid view. It is working well in the local machine. How I can implement this web from with SQL connectivity in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to this are quite large so I will link to some appropriate info that will hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

Your best bet would be to implement this as a [provider hosted add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx), this will allow you to do whatever you want with your solution but still allow it to leverage much of SharePoint functionality (including the UI, should you so choose).

Alternatively you could implement your custom code as a [farm (or so-called "full trust") solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798425.aspx). This path is less desirable since it involves installing your code in to the central SharePoint process and can create stability and upgrade issues for you in the future.

I know this isn't a step-by-step answer, which is often desirable, but the answers to the question you're asking are fairly involved.